# aws-sdk-php 3.0 Call to undefined function Aws\is_valid_hostlabel() with new CloudFrontClient()

Tags: aws-php-sdk

Trying to get the aws-sdk-php 3.0 to work.

**When calling:**

```
$cloudFrontClient = new CloudFrontClient([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-east-1'
]);
```

**I get :**

Call to undefined function Aws\is_valid_hostlabel()

Error at
C:\xampp\htdocs\cscart\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\ClientResolver.php, line: 882

sdk installed with composer under XAMPP

disclaimer: first time poster, fresh coder! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed.

I was unaware that CS CART already have the AWS SDK installed. Once I removed the required_once all was normal.